# Picking a random line from a local text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program that should pick a random line from a local text file, but it seems to not be working.
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id = "gen">Alt Info: </h1>
    <script>
    function readTextFile(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    var split = allText.split('\n')
                    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * split.length);
                    var randomLine = split[randomNum]
                    console.log("All Lines\n"+allText)
                    console.log("Line Numebr\n"+(randomNum+1))
                    console.log("Random Line\n"+randomLine)
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }
    readTextFile("alts.txt");
    </script>
    <button type="button" class=button onclick=document.getElementById("gen").innerHTML = randomLine;>Generate</button>
```

The code above should pick a random line from the 'alts.txt' text file and then when the generate button is clicked it should display that random line to the screen. Instead when I click the generate button, nothing happens.If someone could help me that would be awesome!

Comment: `seems to not be working` See any errors? Have you stepped through the script to see where it's getting stuck? That's the first thing to check

Comment: There is no element with the id "showText" in the HTML you've supplied.

Comment: *seems to not be working* is an absolutely useless problem description. In what way **specifically** is it not working? Don't expect us to read your mind, because weather conditions usually interfere with that long distance. If you want us to know something, then put it in your question. We can't help you if you don't clearly explain the problem.

Comment: I apologize I know my code is a little messed up, I'm fixing it right now. And Ken White sorry about that let me change the question to make it better

Comment: So, I'm guessing that the moderators finally did catch up to you. It's a tough lesson but hopefully one well learned. I do wish you the best of luck and much success in your future programming endeavors though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button` is using an inline handler that's trying to reference a variable not in the global scope.

Inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

The other problem is that `#showText` does not exist - just remove that line from your script.

You have a couple options here. One is to make `randomLine` a global variable so that it can be referenced by the button on demand - which isn't recommended:

```
<script>
var randomLine;
function readTextFile(file)
  // ...
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * split.length);
    randomLine = split[randomNum]
```

But in addition to that, it would be better to remove the inline handler, and add a click listener to the button properly:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('gen').textContent = randomLine;
});
```

Or, even better, don't create a global variable at all; keep the line defined only where it's needed, which is inside the listener:

```
(() => {
  var randomLine;
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", "alts.txt", false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if (rawFile.status === 200) {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        var split = allText.split('\n')
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * split.length);
        randomLine = split[randomNum]
        console.log("All Lines\n" + allText)
        console.log("Line Numebr\n" + (randomNum + 1))
        console.log("Random Line\n" + randomLine)
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);

  const gen = document.getElementById('gen');
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (randomLine) gen.textContent = randomLine;
    else gen.textContent = 'Not retrieved yet';
  });
})();
```

(or use fetch and Promises to handle the asynchronicity instead)

Comment: I thought I did, I'm not sure what else you're looking for? If there are errors, please say what they are

Comment: The code didn't see to work for me? I click the button and no text is generated?

Comment: Again, `didn't work` is not informative at all - what parts of it run or don't run? Where's the error? Please explain the problem

Comment: When I click the button it simply does not display any text